# Swift How to present someone's location on map view?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, cllocation

I am using Mapkit
I got someone's CLLocation and upload it to the cloud database
So how do I present his location to map view?
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already include`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your Info.plist file, you could try something like this :

```
let yourLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)        
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: yourLocation, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```